# What does libstdc++'s std::vector<bool>::data do?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, libstdc++

According to the standard, `std::vector<bool>` has no member function `data()`. However, the following snippet compiles fine with the latest GCC with libstdc++:

```
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<bool> v;
    v.data();
}
```

If we try to use the result, it turns out the return type is `void`.

Is this some gcc extension or a bug?
If the former is true, what does it do?

Comment: I disagree with the dupe. I am aware that the standard does not define the function in question, I'm asking about the behavior of a specific implementation.

Comment: Did you read the source code? GCC is open source.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I admit I did not. Looks like that would have helped. :)

Comment: It looks like it also has `emplace()` and `emplace_back()`.  They're probably no-ops, or something.

Comment: @JustinTime No, it does need those two.

Comment: @T.C. My mistake, I wasn't aware that C++14 added them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_bvector.h` has:

```
// _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
// DR 464. Suggestion for new member functions in standard containers.
// N.B. DR 464 says nothing about vector<bool> but we need something
// here due to the way we are implementing DR 464 in the debug-mode
// vector class.
void
data() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT { }
```

In `/usr/include/c++/4.8/debug/vector` I see the declaration:

```
using _Base::data;
```

So that seems to be the reason: the debug version of `std::vector<bool>` wouldn't compile unless `std::vector<bool>::data` existed.

Comment: [Link to the mentioned DR](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/lwg-defects.html#464) for reference.

Comment: Sad.  It would be useful if it returned a pointer to the packed buffer.  Why not make it `private`?