# vector<bool> raises an error on const data() method

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>

struct TestStruct {
    std::vector<float> float_vect;
    std::vector<bool> bool_vect;
};

void func(const TestStruct & test)
{
    const float * p1 = test.float_vect.data();  //<---   this line works fine
    const bool * p2 = test.bool_vect.data();    //<---   on this line error happens
}

int main()
{
    TestStruct test;
    func(test);
}
```

Error message:

> passing 'const std::vector' as 'this' argument of 'void std::vector::data() [with _Alloc = std::allocator]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

`data()` method of `std::vector` have `const` specified.

Why this method works fine on float vector, and raises an error on boolean vector ?

Comment: I don't think the standard specifies that there is any `std::vector<bool>::data()` member function at all.

Comment: I never had a closer look at it, but [std::vector<bool>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) says `[...]std::vector<bool> is a possibly space-efficient specialization of std::vector for the type bool.[...]` and `[...]The manner in which std::vector<bool> is made space efficient (as well as whether it is optimized at all) is implementation defined.[...]` so the memory layout of `data()` would be not known.

Comment: I don't see `data` method available for [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does libstdc++'s std::vector<bool>::data do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227414/what-does-libstdcs-stdvectorbooldata-do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector<bool>` is a specialization of a good old `vector<T>` and it may be implemented differently from ordinary `vector` (e.g. some space-saving optimizations may be employed). Side-effect of such design is that it does not always behave as ordinary `vector` (many consider `vector<bool>` to be broken because of that).

For example, the reference at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool does not mention `vector<bool>::data()` at all. Therefore - you should not use it when using `vector` with type `bool`. The fact that you don't get an error similar to `method not found` is - in your case - just a matter of how `vector<bool>` is implemented by your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<bool>` is a template specialization of the class `std::vector<T>` in the STL. In order to use less memory, the boolean values are stored by 8 in a byte. It means there is no direct data accessible as you expect because the class doesn't store it in the same way than for other types.

Look at the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) :

> The specialization has the same member functions as the unspecialized vector, except data, emplace, and emplace_back, that are not present in this specialization.